# XNextEvent Blocking At Start of Application

Tags: c++, linux, xlib

I have the following application.

```
#include <FWWindow.h>
#include <FWApplication.h>

int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    FWApplication::Initialize();
    FWWindow *win = new FWWindow(800, 600);
    win->Show();
    FWApplication::Run();
    delete win;
}
```

When I run it it gets stuck on the `XNextEvent()` because it blocks until it gets the next event from the XServer. What I would like to know, is based on the code below, why is the XNextEvent not getting the ConfigureNotify or Expose events after I am calling `XMapWindow()`; I have checked to make sure my application provides the right `Display` based on the address in the watch window of my IDE. What am I missing to get the window to appear?

---

```
Initialize() does the following
```

-

```
FWApplication *FWApplication::Initialize()
{
    if (!_instance)
    {
        _xDisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        if (_xDisplay == NULL)
            throw "Failed to get XDisplay";
        _initialized = true;
        _instance = new FWApplication(); // Calls an empty ctor
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

---

```
FWWindow *win = new FWWindow(800, 600); does the following
```

-

```
FWWindow::FWWindow(int width, int height) :
        clientWidth(width),
        clientHeight(height)
{
    // These are all member variables
    xDisplay = FWApplication::GetMainDisplay();
    xScreen = DefaultScreen(xDisplay);
    xDepth  = DefaultDepth(xDisplay, xScreen);
    xVisual = DefaultVisual(xDisplay,xScreen);
    xAttributes.background_pixel = XWhitePixel(xDisplay, xScreen);
    xAttributes.border_pixel = XBlackPixel(xDisplay, xScreen);
    xAttributes.override_redirect = 0;
    xWindow = XCreateWindow(
                             xDisplay,
                             RootWindow(xDisplay, xScreen),
                             0, 0,
                             width, height,
                             0,
                             xDepth,
                             InputOutput,
                             xVisual,
                             CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask,
                             &xAttributes
                           );

      XSetStandardProperties(
                             xDisplay,
                             xWindow,
                             "glxsimple",
                             "glxsimple",
                             None,
                             NULL,
                             0,
                             NULL
                            );
}
```

---

```
win->Show(); does the following
```

-

```
void FWWindow::Show()
{                                   
    XMapWindow(xDisplay, xWindow); // xWindow and xDisplay defined in ctor above
}
```

---

```
And finaly FWApplication::Run(); does the following
```

-

```
int FWApplication::Run()
{
    if (!_initialized)
        return -1;
    static bool run = true;
    static Display *lDisplay = _xDisplay;
    XEvent xEvent;
    while (run)
    {
        do
        {
            XNextEvent(lDisplay, &xEvent);
            switch (xEvent.type)
            {
            case ConfigureNotify:
                {
                    unsigned int w = xEvent.xconfigure.width;
                    unsigned int h = xEvent.xconfigure.height;
                    // Do something to main widget
                }
            case Expose:
                break;
            }
        } while (XPending(GetMainDisplay()));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifying an event mask in your window's attributes, so `XNextEvent()` won't report any event. You should write something like:

```
xAttributes.background_pixel = XWhitePixel(xDisplay, xScreen);
xAttributes.border_pixel = XBlackPixel(xDisplay, xScreen);
xAttributes.override_redirect = 0;
xAttributes.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask  // for ConfigureNotify
                       | ExposureMask;        // for Expose
```

Comment: That appears to have fixed the hang, however the window still does not appear. I had to modify a working example I had, and have lost my way. Is there anything else that I am missing? I should add that the window appears down on the tool bar, but if I try to maximize it, it does not show. Is this related to size hints?

Comment: It's hard to say... Do you mean the window appears only when it's not maximized, or that it doesn't appear at all? Are the window manager decorations visible? Did you check that your `Expose` handler actually draws anything?

Comment: The window opens but appears to remain minimized in the Desktop system tray. My previous samples all had the window appear with the width and height specified at the Window x,y location specified when calling XCreateWindow. And no I am not drawing anyting I just say XMapWindow. If I don't draw anything does the WindowManager shrink the window all the way down?

Comment: Since you're not drawing anything, the window will remain empty, but the window manager's decorations should still appear, unless you set WM hints to prevent your window from being decorated in the first place (e.g. the `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE` hint).

Comment: The decorations do not appear. The application remains minamized. I have added a default to my switch statement inside even loop and when I try and maximize the window it prints hello world to the terminal, but the window and its decorations do not appear on the screen. I can share the code. http://matthewh.me/scripts/browser/c%2B%2B/win32/win32_winmain_calls_main is where the source is housed. Windowing is the library I am writing atm that has the issues.

Comment: I don't see anything there that would explain the WM decorations not showing. If you are running a modified version of this code, make sure `xAttributes.override_redirect` is actually set to `0` if you specify `CWOverrideRedirect` in the attributes mask. Otherwise, can you run `xwininfo` on your window? It will list its properties and allow you to double-check that everything is set up as you want.